# Dynamic Image Gallery that looks in multiple album folders

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, flash

Can anyone advise on a great image gallery that's dynamic, client side.

Basically what I want is on my website a gallery with multiple albums and images in the albums. To be able to add images dynamically to the folder or remote site (such as Photobucket or Picasa) and the webapage to be able to display them dynamically without any further coding, avoiding the hassle of having to add a lines of code ever time a new image is added.

Anybody using something like this or can point me in the right direction?

Much appreciated.

Comment: I'm not wanting someone to hand me the code on a silver platter. I'm wanting to purchase or even if there is an open source option. There are many gallery's out there, so just wanted some advise if anyone is currently using one or know of one that can do what i'm looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what I was looking for in Picasa Webalbum Integrator javascript library.

http://code.google.com/p/pwi/